# Can's install sass on mac

Tags: macos, sass, rubygems

I have a problem installing sass. I tried gem install sass, it doesnt work so I tried sudo gem install sass but it still doesn't work. What should I do?

```
PASs-iMac:~ user$ sudo gem install sass
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/sass
PASs-iMac:~ user$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command instead

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin sass
```